# Content out of div PHP PDO

Tags: php, html

My content of the subcategories is getting out of the div somehow.
The first one stays on there but the second, third etc is getting out from it.

Any solutions to it?

```
<?php
...
$stmt = $dbh->query('SELECT parent.subcat_id, parent.subcat_name, child.subsubcat_name, child.subcat_id, child.cat_id FROM subcategories parent  JOIN subsubcategories child ON child.cat_id = parent.cat_id');
$lastcat = 0;
$stmt->execute();
$row2 = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

foreach ($row2 as $row) {
    if($lastcat != $row['cat_id']){
        $lastcat = $row['cat_id'];
        echo '<div class="panel panel-default">
              <div class="panel-heading">';
        echo $row['subcat_name'];
        echo '</div><div class="panel-body">';
    }
    echo $row['subsubcat_name'];
    echo "</div></div>";
}

?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should be rewritten like:

```
$close_previous = false;    // special flag
foreach ($row2 as $row) {
    if ($lastcat != $row['cat_id']) {
        $lastcat = $row['cat_id'];

        // check whether you need to close divs from previous block
        if ($close_previous) {
            echo '</div>'; // close .panel-body 
            echo '</div>'; // close .panel-default
        } else {
            // for the first time you don't need 
            // to close divs, so here we skip it
            $close_previous = true;
        }

        echo '<div class="panel panel-default"><div class="panel-heading">';
        echo $row['subcat_name'];
        echo '</div><div class="panel-body">';
    }
    echo $row['subsubcat_name'];
    // add link
    echo '<a href="/test.php?id=' . $row['subcategoryid'] . '">Click</a>';
}

// explicitly close last divs block
echo '</div>'; // close .panel-body 
echo '</div>'; // close .panel-default
```

Also it's a good practice to check your generated html-markup to see what is wrong.

Comment: @u_mulder , Nice! It took me a while to figure out what OP is trying to do. :-)

Comment: How do I make a link which points to test.php?id=$row['subcategoryid'] in this code? Any ideas?

Comment: Nothing particular, just add another `echo` (see update)

Comment: Thanks, but it was meant to be in the body, and that is giving issues.