# Link the subsubcategory to a website with a id

Tags: php, sql

As in the previous answer in my other question (https://stackoverflow.com/a/41524759/6632515), I am trying to create an a href to my subsubcategory which links to a file with an id on the end.

How can I achieve this?

I tried this:

```
<?php
...
$close_previous = false;    // special flag
foreach ($row2 as $row) {
    if ($lastcat != $row['cat_id']) {
        $lastcat = $row['cat_id'];

        // check whether you need to close divs from previous block
        if ($close_previous) {
            echo '</a>';
            echo '</div>'; // close .panel-body 
            echo '</div>'; // close .panel-default
        } else {
            // for the first time you don't need 
            // to close divs, so here we skip it
            $close_previous = true;
        }

        echo '<div class="panel panel-default"><div class="panel-heading">';
        echo $row['subcat_name'];
        echo '</div><div class="panel-body"><a href="test.php?id=';
    }
    echo $row['subcat_id'];
    echo '">';
    echo $row['subsubcat_name'];
    echo "<br>";
    echo '</a>';
    echo $row['subcat_id'];

}

// explicitly close last divs block
echo '</div>'; // close .panel-body 
echo '</div>'; // close .panel-default
?>
```

(sorry for my multiple answers)

Comment: Show us what you've tried and we can take it from there.

Comment: What html output are you getting...and what is missing from it?

Comment: Already got it working thanks to the previous answer.